# Filtering data from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I create a few filters, which can be used by user. So user can send me a value in it or can. How can I check if user send me a value or only null? Now I check it like this, it´s working, but this isn´t ideal solution:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? SearchStuff, int? SearchCustomer, int? SearchWorker, int? SearchOrder, String SearchDate)
    {
        var stuff = from s in db.Orders select s;
        var customer = from c in db.Orders select c;
        var worker = from w in db.Orders select w;
        var order = from o in db.Orders select o;
        var date = from d in db.Orders select d;
        var helper = from d in db.Orders select d;
        IQueryable<Order> filter = order;

       if (SearchCustomer != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchDate) && SearchStuff != null && SearchWorker != null)
        {
            helper = helper.Where(a => a.CustomerId == SearchCustomer).Where(a => a.StuffId == SearchStuff).Where(a => a.WorkerId == SearchWorker).Where(a => a.Date.Contains(SearchDate));
            filter= helper;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, I see it often used in stored procedures as well (I added the first three search options but you can add as many as you like):

```
    Public ActionResult Index(int? searchStuff, int? searchCustomer, int? searchWorker)
    {
        myOrders = db.Orders
            .Where(o => (searchStuff == null || o.StuffId == searchStuff)
                     && (searchCustomer == null || o.CustomerId == searchCustomer)
                     && (searchWorker == null || o.WorkerId == searchWorker));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
var stuff = db.Orders.AsQueryable();
if(searchStuff.HasValue)
{
    stuff = stuff.Where(x=>x.stuffId == searchStuff.Value);
}
if(searchCustomer.hasValue)
{
    stuff = stuff.Where(x=>x.CustomerId == searchCustomer.Value);
}
```

And so on. With this approach you can do more complex filters like e.g. date ranges.